# NumberFormatException when connecting LDAP server with IPv6

Tags: java, ldap, ipv6

I am trying to connect a LDAP server modelled as IPv6 adress, but getting NumberFormatException.

Below is my Code:

```
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + "[2001:1b70:4294:ff0f:0000:0000:0000:0104]" + ":" + "7423");
try {
    ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);
} catch (NamingException e) {
}
```

Your help is much appriciated.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: There is a bug report at Oracle that looks similar: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5042453

Comment: There was a bug reported around a JDK bug when using IPv6 from Java in certain situations. Initially if showed up in JDK 1.5 but I don't know if it's still relevant. ¿Can you try to do a simple test with standard HTTP requests to a IPv6 server? (create one if needed) -- There's actual code handling this exception as a "JDK IPv6 bug": https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-directory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/active_directory/ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java  (line 582!!)